# gcutil: correct way to use the command?

Tags: shell, google-compute-engine, gcutil

I am using `gcutil` in a shell script as follows

```
gcutil deleteinstance --[no]delete_boot_pd: <instance-name>
```

The error message is:

```
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag '[no]delete_boot_pd:'
```

I tried many combinations of the above command, it just doesn't work. All I want to do is to make sure that the deleteinstance does not delete the persistent disk, while not having the shell script stop for user input.

Can somebody help me find the right way to use the command?
The documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/reference/instance#deletetargetinstance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[foo]` typically means that `foo` is optional, so my wild (but likely) guess is that there are two valid parameters that you can use, i.e.

```
--nodelete_boot_pd
--delete_boot_pd
```

I have no knowledge about `gcutil` but I'm sure you will know which one to use in your scenario based on its documentation.

Comment: finally worked "gcutil deleteinstance --nodelete_boot_pd --force instancename" did the trick. thanks.